# Are file names allowed to have '/' in them?

Tags: python-2.7, operating-system

I am confused by a piece of Python code:

```
with open('/dev/null', 'w+') as null:
```

It may be because I do not have knowledge of other Operating Systems, but I thought file names are forbidden to have '/' character. If so, I do not understand how this is a valid command.

Now I do understand that when using the open function in Python, if the file exist in a directory other than the current working directory, one has to prepend the path to the file name argument. However, this does not seem to be the case here because the file name argument for the open function is simply '/dev/null/'.  Is 'null' the file name.

Is this related to this:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_device

"in some operating systems, the null device is a device file that discards all data written to it but reports that the write operation succeeded. This device is called /dev/null on Unix and Unix-like systems"

Comment: That's a file path. `dev` is a directory. `null` is the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Unix systems, file name cannot contain forward slash as it's used as directory separator. A file can't have a name of exactly one or two dots as they're used for "current directory" and "parent directory", too. A path starting with a forward slash is an absolute path, going all the way down the directory tree from the root path.

In that code, it opens `/dev/null`, a special character device that discards everything written to it and reports write success. It's possible that in some cases one wants to discard the output from a specific function, like `subprocess.run`. In this case, opening a handle to the null device is useful.

Comment: you nailed it, thanks. We are invoking the subprocess module